# Returning right Java type of an typed class by passing the class with generics

Tags: java, generics

For a better understanding of my question, see the following classes:

```
public interface Invoker<R> {
  public String getName();
  public R getResult();
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class RepairFetcher implements Invoker<List<String>> {

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
  }

  @Override
  public List<String> getResult() {
    return new ArrayList<String>();
  }

}
```

The class where it goes wrong:

```
public class OperationService {

   public <R> R invoke(Class<R> invoker, Object... parameters) {
     WebserviceOperation<R> operation = new WebserviceOperation<R>(invoker);
     Invoker<R> instance = operation.getInstance();

     return instance.getResult();
   }

}
```

The main class:

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    OperationService operationService = new OperationService();
    operationService.invoke(RepairFetcher.class, new Object[] {});

  }

}
```

**The problem:**
At this moment the method

> operationService.invoke(RepairFetcher.class, new Object[] {});

returns an RepairFetcher, which is not so weird because of the argument in the invoke method:

> Class invoker

Which returns R, which is a RepairFetcher.class.

**What I want**
I don't want the invoke method to return the RepairFetcher class, but I want it to return the declared Type, which is List< String>.

Is this possible, and if so, how to implement this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, but try:

```
public <T, R extends Invoker<T>> T invoke(Class<R> invoker, Object... parameters) {
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted doesn't compile in the current shape (it misses some parts), but judging from what you're trying to do, you should be aware that `Class` is parameterized with the type of the class; so, the type of the `String.getClass()` is `Class<String>`.

That said, your function definition

```
public <R> R invoke(Class<R> invoker, Object... parameters) {
```

should probably be something like

```
public <R> R invoke(Class<Invoker<R>> invoker, Object... parameters) {
```

so you can be sure to return the same type that your invoker returns.

Answer (score 0):

RepairFetcher implement `Invoker<List<String>>` so RepairFetcher is a `Invoker<List<String>>` and the return is good.

If you test this:

RepairFetcher instanceof `Invoker<List<String>>`, the answer must be true.

PS: I replace < by ( because the editor has a problem with <